# How to store old messages

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

So I am new to discord API and I am currently trying to create a small simple discord bot.

The thing that I am trying to do is archive the messages that have been sent in a specific channel. Not only those deleted, or edited but all of them.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `.fetchMessages([options])` .

Default messages get is 50.

Options object you can put as where you want to start collecting the messages from. Place the message inside options and it will start downloading starting from the message.

Comment: Probably a bit late to ask this, but its not getting recognised as a function any ideas?
`client.getChannelLogs(msg.channel, 100, 'after',function(error,messages){...`

Comment: Does the function exists? Also, does the function's scope reaches the line of code? Finally what does the function does/return etc? If you want you can read up on the library too if its more of a trouble in it reading the function itself.

Comment: I have seen the library, the function is shown in the discord API, so its supposed to exist. The line is being reached but then the error pops up saying the line `client.getChannelLogs` isnt a function. That shouldnt have been an error as all I am doing is calling the discor function,

Comment: Then this most likely is a library or the compiler problem, try reinstalling the library and check the other required library(versions too) If problem persists, i recommend contacting the developers(They are at a discord chat, you should be able to find the link somewhere in the github's discord.js library or googling)

Comment: So I found what the problem was. I am gonna leave here a link in case anyone else gets stuck at the same thing. The `getChannelLogs(channel, limit, options, callback)` is not supported anymore, instead its the `fetchMessages`. You should better change your answer Wen! Link to new documentation: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/welcome

Comment: Ok I changed my answer, thanks for correcting my mistake and letting me know.